# With SQL Server add x number of days to a date in sql but also pass in the number of business days in a week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

In SQL Server I would like to add x number of business days to a date but also pass in the amount of business days in a week. ie could be 5,6 ,7.

I found this on stack overflow that handles 5 days but not sure how to modify it so that you could specify the number of working days per week.

```
CREATE FUNCTION[dbo].[AddBusinessDays]
    (@Date date, @n INT)
RETURNS DATE AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @d INT;
    SET @d = 4 - SIGN(@n) * (4-DATEPART(DW, @Date));

    RETURN DATEADD(D, @n + ((ABS(@n) + @d - 2) / 5) * 2 * SIGN(@n) - @d / 7, @Date);
END
```

Comment: At this point you might want to consider creating a calendar table - at one row per day you're talking less than 4000 rows to cover the next ten years - and then you can have column(s) for features of dates that are important to *your* organization (such as whether a particular day counts as a business day). Once you have the calendar table, writing a query to find e.g. the next business day or to add x business days onto a date tends to be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is it, I have converted it to a stored procedure for better understanding.

I have used SQL Server.

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[AddBusinessDaysP]
(@Date date,@n INT,@wds INT)
as
BEGIN
--exec AddBusinessDaysP '9/25/2014',2,4

Declare @totWeekEnds int
Set @totWeekEnds = (Case When @n > 7 then (@n / 7) else 1 end)  * (7-@wds)

Declare @totDays int

Set @totDays = @n  + @totWeekEnds

Select @n as DaysToAdd,@wds as DaysInWeek,@totWeekEnds as TotalWeekEnds,@totDays as TotalDaysToAdd,Dateadd(dd,@totDays,@Date) as Answer

END
```

I have also converted SP into Function as you want.

```
Alter FUNCTION[dbo].[AddBusinessDays](@Date date,@n INT,@wds INT)
RETURNS DATE AS 
BEGIN
--Select [dbo].[AddBusinessDays]('9/25/2014',2,5)

Declare @totWeekEnds int
Set @totWeekEnds = (Case When @n > 7 then (@n / 7) else 1 end)  * (7-@wds)

Declare @totDays int

Set @totDays = @n  + @totWeekEnds

Return Dateadd(dd,@totDays,@Date) 

END
```

Comment: Thanks AK47, I had one issue though when i tried the function. If I try SELECT dbo.AddBusinessDays ('2014-09-26' ,1 ,6 ) and 26th is a Friday , it should return Saturday the 27th which is the next business day in a 6 day week but its returning Sunday the 28th. Hmm maybe sql treats Sunday as the first day, I'm not sure, will have to investigate.

Comment: Hmmm, Correct, Will try to sort this issue.